# What do people think of jira studio?

Tags: jira, saas

What are peoples opinions on jira studio? i.e. using the hosted product for a large company. Especially with hosted source control and reliability of the service?

Is this product up to large scale implementations yet?

Comment: Not really an answer but I chose a local Jira instead of hosted for the flexibility of using plugins & other customisations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using JIRA Studio (hosted) extensively over the last few weeks with a Java project. So far my experience has been resoundingly positive, with the following caveats:

- Setting up Elastic Bamboo requires filing a support ticket. While admittedly the process is fully automated and very easy, it can still take a day or two before you can begin setting up your builds;
- In my opinion, SVN hosting is limiting. I've been very much looking forward to working with git or Mercurial, but I'm not aware of any plans to add support for those. You can certainly find a separate host for your sources, but you'd be losing on ease of use, out-of-the-box integration with issue tracking and the JIRA dashboard (which I've grown to absolutely love) and will have to sign with a second provider.

I would rate the primary advantages as:

- Very low integration cost (compared to e.g. setting up your own Bugzilla+Mediawiki+Hudson setup);
- Relatively low TCO, particularly if you have a small staff and no Linux hackers to get you started up;
- Very smooth administration and usage experience. I've very rarely had to look in the documentation, and then it was usually clean and informative.

Comment: Apparently Mercurial is now supported as another option. I'll update my post if/when we migrate to that.